# Click zone for a non rectangle object

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a few triangles positioned like these: 
[image]

Each triangle is a DIV and positioned with CSS. And now I need to change the clickable zone of each DIV because the DIVs are rectangles but I display triangles. How is that possible? Is it? :)

The full HTML is created by vanilla JS and futhermore I want to add a click event for each triangle.

```
<div id="Row_1" class="row">
    <div id="Field_1_1" class="field">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Field_1_2" class="field">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would probably add a click event to the outermost containing element and then use the coordinates given by the event to work out which triangle was clicked.

Comment: Please add the CSS so we can see how you made them triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Divs will always be rectangles, although you can give them a border-radius to produce circles, semicircles, rounded rectangles, etc.

If you really want triangle-level clicking I'd recommend using svg instead of styling divs. With svg you can detect clicks on individual shapes with per-pixel accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in SVG will allow per-pixel click detection, that just wouldn't be possible with divs.

Positioning the triangles can be done directly using their points, but it's often easier to have each "up" and "down" triangle use the same points, and put it inside a transform to make positioning them easier.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moertx29/

HTML:

```
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(75 0)">
    <polygon class="up" points="75,0 0,150 150,150" onclick="alert('1')" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0 150)">
    <polygon class="up" points="75,0 0,150 150,150" onclick="alert('2')" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(75 150)">
    <polygon class="down" points="0,0 150,0 75,150" onclick="alert('3')" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(150 150)">
    <polygon class="up" points="75,0 0,150 150,150" onclick="alert('4')" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}

polygon {
  stroke:purple;
  stroke-width:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}

polygon.down {
  fill:red;
}

polygon.up {
  fill:yellow;
}
```

Comment: I mean, I'd put the polygons all in the one SVG and either increment their x values or put them in a transform to offset them, but yeah, that's what I was getting at.

Comment: @FTWinston, do you know if it is possible to define the points in css? I cant find anything relevant

Comment: Still the same overlapping issue ;-) I think I have to convert my full code to a single svg. Yesterday I tried a combination with img & map but the click zone is still the image, only limitated by the map...

Comment: Wow I didnt even notice that :/

Comment: @Krøsh it might be possible to relatively-position triangles using CSS, but I wouldn't trust it without testing. SVG's transform is probably the most straightforward way of positioning each triangle without editing the vertices of each, see e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/moertx29/

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply and thank you for your edit. I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w65nkp94/1/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<a href=""><div class="triangleUp"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="triangleDown"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="triangleUp"></div></a>
<a href=""><div class="triangleDown"></div></a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size:0;
  margin:50px;
}

.triangleUp {
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #555;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:-25px;
}

.triangleDown {
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:-25px;
}
```

If you want to add a javascript function, remove the < a> tags and add a "onclick" event to the divs, like this:

```
<body>
<div class="triangleUp" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
<div class="triangleDown" onclick="myFunction2()"></div>
<div class="triangleUp" onclick="myFunction3()"></div>
<div class="triangleDown" onclick="myFunction4()"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's impressive, but if you remove all but a single triangle and give it cursor: pointer and an onClick attribute you'll see that the click area still appears to be a rectangle, not a triangle.
https://jsfiddle.net/r15dt73q/

Comment: I tested it too and unfortunatly it dont works. 

https://jsfiddle.net/zave6dsp/ If you click the secound div on the top left side the alert is 3 because the divs still overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip-path`:

```css
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path